# Wrong lsb-release after release upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, do-release-upgrade

Today I did a LTS upgrade from trusty to xenial using `do-release-upgrade`. It went through without an error. But after the upgrade I'm not sure on which version my system is now.

The `do-release-upgrade` tool said it would upgrade to xenial and my `sources.list` now points to the xenial package archive. `apt` claims all packages are fully upgraded (doing `update`, `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`).
But when I run `lsb_release -a` I'm still getting this

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

And when I check the version of `base-files` (which to my understanding contains the `/etc/lsb-release` file) with `dpkg --list` I'm getting version `10.1` which is the most recent package version in the **bionic** package archive.

Also when I run `do-release-upgrade -c` it still tries to upgrade to xenial.

I must say I'm pretty confused. Has anyone any idea what's going on?

#### Update

I think I know what happened here. While updating, the installation process for `base-files` asks for user confirmation on whether to update the `/etc/lsb-release` file if it was edited since the last installation.

```
Configuration file '/etc/lsb-release'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
```

The file looked like it had the same contents as in the trusty `base-file` package before updating, so I don't really understand why I got get asked before replacing it. Anyways, I think I might have taken the default action, resulting in a mismatch between the actually installed release and the contents of the file.

Replacing the file with the one from the xenial package allowed me to successfully update to bionic with `do-release-upgrade`. This time I selected to update the `lsb-release` while upgrading. Manually messing with the contents of that file before upgrading again didn't seem to have any adverse effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lsb_release` is a Python script that simply reads from the file `/etc/lsb-release` and dumps output to the screen. You can edit the file using:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/lsb-release
```

Then change the contents to suit your platform. Mine contains:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"
```

Comment: I was aware of that, but isn't this strange? Do you have any idea as to how this has happened? Won't just changing the contents of that file leave my system in an even more inconsistent state?

Comment: @heilerich I found many instances where this has happened to other users. I didn't find a reason though.

Comment: Replacing my lsb-release file with yours allowed me to upgrade to bionic. Manually messing with the contents of that file before upgrading again didn't seem to have any adverse effects.