# Update to 20.10 failed according to lsb_release -a

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, 20.10, lsb-release

I tried updating my computer to Ubuntu 20.10, however it seems to have failed.

What I did:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This seemed to have worked, it ran through and the computer restarted with a gorilla welcoming me as new background image. However `lsb_release -a` tells me I'm still on 20.04:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (fossa-bulbasaur X38)
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Running `sudo do-release-upgrade` again ends in "aborting"

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                       
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1’338 kB]                                                                                              
Fetched 1’339 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                             
authenticate 'groovy.tar.gz' against 'groovy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'groovy.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                                                              
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/main Sources [1’300 kB]                                                      
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/universe i386 Packages [13.8 kB]                                   
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security/universe amd64 Packages [17.3 kB]                                  

[...]
                            
Fetched 58.9 MB in 6s (9’192 kB/s)                                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                                                              
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                  

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

I don't know in what state my system currently is... The sources all have groovy packets, the background image changed, but the OS clearly still is 20.04.

Would be glad for some help on this...

OS: Ubuntu 20.04, 5.8.0-26-generic /
Hardware: Dell XPS 13 9310

Comment: The `lsb_release` command has been known to give misleading results. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099247/wrong-lsb-release-after-release-upgrade

Comment: thanks @Jos. So how would I conclude what OS version I am really running then?
Settings > About shows `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (fossa-bulbasaur X38)`

Comment: All your packages are installed from the `groovy` repository. You are definitely on 20.10.

Comment: i'm not entirely convinced by that. i get visual pop ups asking me to upgrade to 20.10. but then nothing happens

Comment: I have the same laptop and the same problem. I bet it has something to do with whatever causes the dell logo to appear in "details" as well. I don't think it causes harm outside of the upgrade prompt. Hopefully we can upgrade fine to 21.04 though when it's released.

Comment: It is blocking me from upgrading to 21.04. I have a Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (on a Dell Precision 3450 workstation with Ubuntu 20.04 preinstalled) and traced it back to the file `/usr/lib/os-release` by reading the code of `lsb_release` (which is a python script).

The file `/usr/lib/os-release` is part of the package `base-files`, but is for some reason not updated when a newer version of the package is installed during the release upgrade. That's probably due to customizations by Dell, I have no idea.

In any case, I managed to solve the problem by downloading and unpacking the deb package and overwriting the file `/usr/lib/os-release` with the new version by hand. When running `sudo do-release-upgrade` after that, it offered me to upgrade to `21.10` as expected, instead of offering `21.04` again.

After upgrading to `21.10`, `lsb_release -a` was again off and told me that I was still on `21.04`. After replacing `/usr/lib/os-release` with the newest version by hand again, it seems to work now.

I'll report back if it's obviously broken.

Update: It seemed my hack resulted in a broken system, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374621/curl-dynamic-linking-problem-in-21-10).

Update 2: I think I fixed the problem, by removing the packages `dca-enabler-packages dca-enabler`, see discussion see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374621/curl-dynamic-linking-problem-in-21-10). I also installed the package `linux-image-generic` and changed the boot order to boot it by default since the oem kernel doesnt' get updates through the non LTS releases if i understand correctly.

Answer (score -1):

User jos from the comment section is right. If you have the groovy repos in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and do

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

you have technically an up-to-date Ubuntu 20.10 installation, regardless of what the text file says in `/etc/lsb-release`.

I don't know how you ended up with wrong `lsb-release` info. I would recommend you to cleanly install Ubuntu 20.04, as pointed out in your other question thread, as this gives you gives you a lot more possibilities currently to try things out easily with your Dell XPS 13, since Dell is officially supporting that release for that machine.

Comment: OK, thank you for the update!
so far i've dreaded another clean install and reconfiguration of my whole system...
i might do it though..

Comment: This is not a supported method of upgrading Ubuntu (although it is on Debian), and it is not what shiftux did, so it's a rather confusing answer!